# How to access the internet via other VPC NAT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

### Background

I have two Google Cloud VPC networks. VPC `A` and `B`. `B` network was peered into `A` network.

The VPC `A` has a NAT gateway with connectivity to the internet.

Instances running in VPC `B` has no internet connectivity.

### Question

I want to connect VPC `B` to use `A` NAT in order to get internet connectivity.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per [VPC Network Peering interaction](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-peering) this isn't possible:

> Cloud NAT gateways are associated with subnet IP address ranges in a single region and a single VPC network. A Cloud NAT gateway created in one VPC network cannot provide NAT to VMs in other VPC networks connected by using VPC Network Peering, even if the VMs in peered networks are in the same region as the gateway.

It is possible to achieve the result you are looking for by using a Shared VPC instead of VPC Network Peering, this would allow an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc) you have be the steps you need to follow to create a Shared VPC.

Comment: Right. But this answer also mean that I cannot create a forward rule from VPC `B` that will forward all the traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 to other VPC (`A`)?

Comment: Prefer a shared VPC to a VPC peering in this case